# The problem approaching private number of class

Tags: c++

My program receives width and breadth of rectangle 
My output would be rectangle and specific point which can get from second line input. If number is odd , it will represent 'y' coordinate, else it will represent 'x' coordinate.
My problem is

```
pt.mark(pt.get_p(), pt.get_q());
```

this one.
In my method "mark",

```
buf << "+-" << setw(x() - 2) << "" << "-+" << endl;
```

x() represents " 0 " . So , my rectangle looks like

[image]

[image]
I don't know why this happen , because my approach to the private number of Class "Point" is not wrong using method x().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int _x, _y;
public:
    Point(int x=0, int y=0): _x(x), _y(y) {}
    int x() { return _x; }
    int x(int n) {return _x = n;}
    int y() { return _y; }
    int y(int n) {return _y=n;}
};

class MovingPoint: public Point
{
private:
    int p, q;
    vector<int> nums;
public:
    MovingPoint(int x = 0, int y = 0): Point(x, y) {}
    MovingPoint(vector<int> a) : nums(a) {}
    void mark(int x, int y);
    void calculate();
    int get_p() {return p;}
    int get_q() {return q;}
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, MovingPoint p)
{
    return out << "(" << p.x() << ", " << p.y() << ")";
}


void MovingPoint::mark(int a, int b)
{
    ostringstream buf;

    vector<int> lengths;
    vector<string> words;
    int cnt;
    char prev = buf.fill('-');
    buf << "+-" << setw(x() - 2) << "" << "-+" << endl;
    char pres = buf.fill(' ');

    for (int i = 0; i < y() ; i++)
    {
        if (i == b - 1)
            buf << "| " << setw(a) << "." << setw(x() - a) << " |" << endl;
        else
            buf << "| " << setw(x()) << " |" << endl;
    }
    char prev1 = buf.fill('-');
    buf << "+-" << setw(x() - 2) << "" << "-+" << endl;
    buf.fill(prev1);
    cout << buf.str();
}

void MovingPoint::calculate()
{
    p = 0;
    q = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() ; i++)
    {
        if (nums[i] % 2 == 0)
            p++;
        else
            q++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    vector<int> nums;

    cin >> x >> y;
    MovingPoint pt(x, y);
    while (cin >> x)
    {
        nums.push_back(x);
    }
    pt = MovingPoint(nums);
    pt.calculate();
    pt.mark(pt.get_p(), pt.get_q());
}
```

Comment: This is obviously not C.

Comment: What do you mean by `"If number is odd , it will represent 'y' coordinate, else it will represent 'x' coordinate."?` in your 2nd example `12 4` nether are odd, so where does the `y` coordinate come from? (yet that is still a 12 x 4 rectangle.)

Comment: 12 4 represents the width and breadth of rectangle. Cartesian coordinate of Specific point is referred with the fact that number is odd or not

Comment: Okay, that clears up the confusion.

Comment: in `pt = MovingPoint(nums);`, old x/y are replaced (by uninitialized values BTW).

Comment: I assume you want to combine the data into one object, but `pt = MovingPoint(nums);` overwrites the data completely with the one from the new object, i.e. the data `_x` and `_y` values contain values initialized by the `Point` constructor receiving 0 parameters and therefore they are both 0. Furthermore a Inheritance relationship between `Point` and `MovingPoint` does not seem like a good idea: The only thing they have in common is the fact that they contain a 2d value, but it doesn't even have the same meaning in both x, y coordinates vs width and height of the rect.

Comment: Then how can I add vector information to my class "pt" not using constructor??

Comment: You will need a public setter: `void set_nums(const vector<int> &nums) { this->nums = nums;}`

Answer (score 0):

You might do, with some renaming:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

struct Rectangle
{
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
};

struct Point
{
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
};

void draw(const Rectangle& rect, const Point& pt)
{
    std::ostringstream buf;

    buf.fill('-');
    buf << "+-" << setw(x() - 2) << "" << "-+" << endl;
    buf.fill(' ');

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rect.height() ; i++)
    {
        if (i == pt.y - 1)
            buf << "| " << setw(pt.x) << "." << setw(rect.width() - pt.x) << " |" << endl;
        else
            buf << "| " << setw(rect.width()) << " |" << endl;
    }
    char prev1 = buf.fill('-');
    buf << "+-" << setw(rect.width() - 2) << "" << "-+" << endl;
    buf.fill(prev1);
    std::cout << buf.str();
}

Point calculate(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    Point p{0, 0};

    for (auto e : v)
    {
        if (e % 2 == 0)
            p.x++;
        else
            p.y++;
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    Rectangle r;

    std::cin >> r.width >> r.height;

    std::vector<int> nums;
    int n;
    while (std::cin >> n)
    {
        nums.push_back(n);
    }
    Point pt = calculate(nums);
    draw(r, pt);
}
```